# Connection reset by peer @ io_fillbuf - fd:8 (HTTPClient::KeepAliveDisconnected)

Tags: android, docker, calabash, calabash-android

I am running calabash test for android. Everything has been working fine so far. But at some points, it is raising the following error

> HTTPClient::KeepAliveDisconnected: Connection reset by peer @ io_fillbuf - fd:8  (HTTPClient::KeepAliveDisconnected)

And one more thing I have missed to specify that the issue is raising when the whole test is running on the docker container. The same file does run on the local without any error.

I have searched a lot to find an answer for this and could not find one so far. All kinda help are appreciated in advance.